# Ionic build shows white screen on android SDK platform below 29

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3

When i run `ionic cordova build android --prod`, and install the debug.apk on multiple devices with the latest Android 10.0(Q) it does works.

The problem comes when i try to install it on a version below like Android 9.0 (Pie), there is when it get's stuck on a white screen.
I have already installed the SDK platforms on Android Studio.
Those are my preferences on config.xml,  already changed it a few times but always getting a white screen on an older phone. Any help would be aprecciated.

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />
<preference name="android-maxSdkVersion" value="29" />
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="29" />
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It should not get stucked woth versions, did you try to remove the build then do a rebuild?

Comment: Already tried that same results

Comment: There is nothing named maxsdkversion, its target sdk version, there is only minsdkversion and target sdk version, any way after build, go to gradle file in android build and change the versions to the versions you need to try, if it succeed from this way, then the problem of app crash is from these prefences

Comment: you can't have something called maxsdkversion , for white screen you need to inspect the app on chrome and see what is the error